# Why do i loose all wallets and need to resync after symlinking chain folder?

Tags: daedalus

Since my partition with `/home` on it started to fill up, i relocated the folder `~/.local/share/Daedalus/mainnet/chain` onto another drive.

After moving the files and symlinking to the new location, i restarted Daedalus. Now all my wallets are gone and Daedalus is resyncing from 0%. (Which is now ongoing for 16hours and is currently at 72%...)

This is confusing to me, since it was perfectly synced before moving the `chain` folder, so i would only expect to re-sync the new blocks while moving (like less than 1%). And especially that all my wallets are now gone, is weird to me (not a big deal, of course i've got the seed phrases for all of them).

But this is rather inconvenient and i don't understand why this is happening. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in order to use symlinks accross devices, one needs to alter the `nix` command to mount these locations.

See this answer: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/9340